# Eigen::SelfAdjointView::rankUpdate slower than A += w*w.transpose()

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3

Tested speed of Eigen::SelfAdjointView::rankUpdate with Eigen::Matrix4d

comparing to naive  A += w*w.transpose()
and it was 2 times slower.

1. What im doing wrong?
2. Can i speed up this computations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For small fixed sized expressions you can't save anything with `SelfAdjointView::rankUpdate`, it rather adds overhead because it needs to make sure that only elements of one half are modified. In your case a simple

```
A.noalias() += w*w.adjoint();
```

should give near optimal code (adding the `.noalias()` avoids a copy into a temporary).